# What is the best marker for writing on glass?

Tags: storage, organization

I am looking for a permanent marker for writing on glass spice containers that can endure being washed.  I thought of just using sticky paper labels but they will not endure washing.  Should I go for oil-based markers?

Comment: A low priced electric engraver. Temporarily tape your text inside the glass container, trace the text on the outside of the container remove the taped text from inside the container and your done. This technique can be used to make personalize drinking glasses as gifts.

Comment: that sounds like a bit of an overkill

Comment: You can buy glass pens (intended for crafts) at art supply shops.

Comment: What type of washing?  Sharpie might hold up if you're not actively scrubbing at it.  Brother makes some label makers that laminate the labels (the P-Touch TZ cartridges), but I've never tried washing them.

Comment: Sharpie also makes paint markers which tend to write better on really slick surfaces.

Comment: But if the jars are being washed, they're empty, right? Would it really hurt to keep the marker handy so you can rewrite it? Or even completely change what you put in the jar by intentionally washing off the sharpie?

Answer (score 1):

You can also engrave on glass using a product from Joannns/Michaels called Amour Etch.  I've engraved 9x13 glassware with it, and given it as gifts.  Yes, it's washable.  Amour Etch is something that you have to use carefully.  Google it.

Here's a handy [instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OGe2hmlv94)

Comment: Agreed. This is the only solution that won't wear off. Even the enameled labels on my glass measuring cups wears off. I replace it with etching. We also etch our name on casserole dishes to make sure the find their way home.

Comment: @Sobachatina I know the OP said the spice jars would be washed, but I'm sure they won't get washed nearly as much as measuring cups. Waterproof labels that take a while to wash off (and can be replaced) sounds a bit easier than making a bunch of tiny stencils...